# Как получить шапку Lifesaver? Что это за "бродяга"?

Tags: поддержка, новогодние-шляпы

Я не понимаю и никогда ничего подобного не видел. Если можно помимо деталей, также пример такого вопроса.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[Бродяга](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/40/tumbleweed)** - это бронзовый значок, дающийся человеку, вопрос которого сообщество проигнорировало. Описание гласит:

> "Задал вопрос, за который не голосовали, на который не отвечали, не
>   комментировали и мало просматривали за неделю."

Пройдя по ссылке в статистику значка Вы можете просмотреть относительно свежие вопросы за которые получают "бродягу".

За что получил "бродягу" конкретный юзер можно посмотреть, зайдя в его профиль, кликнуть на "посмотреть все знаки" в правом нижнем углу, кликнуть на значок знака "бродяга".

Comment: Есть удобная шпаргалка по всем Бродягам и их заслугам: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/40/tumbleweed